# WPF Calling function in Page from "Master" Window

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a button in a Window that needs to call a function in pages contained within a frame.  The page inside the frame will change based on a navigation contained in the main Window, so I will know the current Page within the frame.

Can someone help with how to call function in frame pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to approach this from an MVVM perspective, you'll want to make sure you're not working with the actual view here, but the ViewModel abstraction of it. In that case, your parent Window is probably backed by a ViewModel that contains some sort of a collection that backs your pages in the frame/tab control/container of choice. In that case, the button should link to a command on your Window-backing ViewModel and use the selected item in the collection to access the function. If you do not have a direct reference in this fashion (for example loading in from another module or something for frame contents) you can also use EventAggregator from the Prism/CAL libraries and publish an event when the window button is pressed and set up your pages to receive that event and handle the call there. EventAggregator can be a slick way to handle cross-module logic in a clean way.

Comment: Ended up using the following to call functions within the content frame. Can also pass in an object array to get data back from the function.
frmMain.Content.GetType().GetMethod("SaveFrm").Invoke(frmMain.Content, new object[0]);